# PHP File_exist() not working - Checking if File Exist in WordPress Theme Directory

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, wp-filesystem

I am trying to check if a certain archive file template exists in the WP theme directory. This is my code, I am not sure what I am missing here.

```
<?php 

$file_name = '/archive.php';
$base_template_dir = get_template_directory_uri();

$file_uri = $base_template_dir.$file_name;
$file_uri = str_replace('http://', '', $file_uri);
$file_uri = str_replace('https://', '', $file_uri);

$file_uri = str_replace($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], '', $file_uri);

if (file_exists($file_uri)) {
    echo 'File Found: '.$file_uri;
} else {
    echo 'File Not Found: '.$file_uri;
}
?>
```

Comment: The WP root directory or the theme directory?

Comment: What is `$mPath`? I don't see it defined anywhere in your code.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, that was a Typo.. I meant the theme directory

Comment: @SallyCJ that was a typo… it has been corrected to reflect the `$file_uri` variable – However, the code still doesn't work even though i have an archive.php file available in the theme's directory

Comment: Yes @Tamara, I knew `$file_uri` wouldn't work, and I was only telling you that you've used an undefined variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of this code is unnecessary. You're attempting to convert a URL to a path when you could just use the function that returns a path.

```
$path = get_theme_file_path( 'archive.php' );

if ( file_exists( $path ) ) {
    echo 'File Found: '. $path;
} else {
    echo 'File Not Found: '. $path;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, `get_template_directory_uri()` was the wrong function to start with. `get_theme_file_path()` worked perfectly